# Как добавить линк на недостающую библиотеку в командную строку компилятора?

Tags: кросс-компиляция, компоновщик, библиотеки, openwrt, linux

Собираю пакет под OpenWRT. При компиляции выскакивает ошибка:

> ```
> /home/OpenWRT_AA/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_r2_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/lib/gcc/mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/4.6.3/../../../../mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/bin/ld:  src/wimax.o: undefined reference to symbol 'g_type_init'
> ```

Потом компилятор дает подсказку:

> /home/OpenWRT_AA/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_r2_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/lib/gcc/mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/4.6.3/../../../../mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/bin/ld:
> note: 'g_type_init' is defined in DSO
> /home/OpenWRT_AA/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so
> try adding it to the linker command  line

Как добавить этот линк в командную строку для кросс-компиляции отдельного пакета?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте добавить

```
-lgobject-2.0
```

Возможно, вам ещё понадобится

```
-L/home/OpenWRT_AA/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/lib/
```

(Вот [ещё по теме](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5751380/276994).)

Comment: Этот вопрос на stackoverflow я видел. :(
Хочу уточнить.
make package/my/package/compile  -L/home/OpenWRT_AA/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/lib/ -lgobject-2.0 

? Или как-то по-другому?

Comment: @Руслан: по идее, да. Может быть, на самом деле надо править makefile?

Comment: ruslan@ruslan-laptop:~/OpenWRT_AA$ make package/gctwimax/compile -L/home/rusink/OpenWRT_AA/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/lib -lgobject-2.0
make: неверный ключ — «/»
Потом идет help, а потом выдает вот это: 
==Эта программа собрана для i686-pc-linux-gnu
О найденных ошибках пишите на <bug-make@gnu.org>==

Не пойму, где здесь лишний ключ? :(

Comment: Можно и makefile  поправить, но сначала скомпилировать надо, а не получается :(

Comment: @Руслан: возьмите весь путь в кавычки, должно проглотить

Comment: Не-а, не глотает. Ни с кавычками ни с апострофами.
Выдает то же самое:


laptop:~/OpenWRT_AA$ make package/gctwimax/compile '-L/home/rusink/OpenWRT_AA/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/lib -lgobject-2.0'
make: неверный ключ — «/»
Использование: make [КЛЮЧ]... [ЦЕЛЬ]...
Ключи:
  -b, -m игнорируются для совместимости.
 
   =Дальше идет целый список == и в завершении вот это:

Эта программа собрана для i686-pc-linux-gnu
О найденных ошибках пишите на <bug-make@gnu.org>

Comment: @Руслан: о, там же написано всё! Пробуйте так:

    make '-L/home/rusink/OpenWRT_AA/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/lib' -lgobject-2.0
 package/gctwimax/compile